# Cannot do Select All Statement in sqlite

Tags: android, sql, typescript, sqlite

So I have already several queries. But this simple one doesnt work. And the error code is not really helpful.

I have a table called 'Activity' and I want to select all of them.

I have a working query, this one:

```
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE status =? OR status = NULL';
return this.database.executeSql(query, [1]);
```

This works and delivers the expected results.

But this query here:

```
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Activity';
return this.database.executeSql(query);
```

produces this error here:

[image]

Both queries return a `Promise<any>`. Both results get stored in a simple variable.

The method `executeSql` requires one parameter, the second one is optional. Also, you can see in the error, that 6 results were found, which is true.

Does anybody know what I did wrong here?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: if you need additional information, simply tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to this.

```
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE status =? OR status IS NULL';
```

You can't check for null values as your initially did ( = NULL)
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-is-null/

Answer (score 0):

i really dont understand the problem. However I just did a little hack.

Instead of using

`SELECT * FROM Activity` I simply say `SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE status >?` and running the statement with

`return this.database.executeSql(query, [-1]);`

The question mark symbolizes a parameter. status is always 0 or bigger.